# MediaWiki Docker Official Image - Connection Refused by MySQL

Tags: mysql, docker, mediawiki

I'm trying to install MediaWiki using the official docker image at [MediaWiki Docker Official Image](https://hub.docker.com/_/mediawiki)

I'm on a Windows 10 box and used docker-compose with the `stack.yml` file that the page has on the instructions.

It all deploys and starts, but when I connect and try to run the initial configuration, I run into errors.

I changed the database username to "wikiuser" and use "example" as the password - as set in the yml file.  When I click "Continue" I get

```
Cannot access the database: :real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory.
```

If I change the "Database host" from `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`, I get: `Cannot access the database: :real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused.`

I even tried it in the "Try in PWD" link and had the same results on the "Play with Docker" virtual machine.

Is something missing from the yml file? I also tried adding a `ports` setting in the yml file and exposed 3306:3306, but got the same results.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 14):

Ugh.  I got it to work by changing the `Database host` to simply `database`
Or to the name of the database-service in `docker-compose` file if you changed it.

This should probably be in their setup documentation.

Comment: OMG, thank you. This should be marked as the answer. I have had issues with multiple projects' documentation on Docker Hub, unfortunately.

Comment: I did struggle with that too and luckally found this post, thank you. Although it should be clear looking at their docker-compose file found here: https://hub.docker.com/_/mediawiki. However they are using the legacy docker links: https://docs.docker.com/network/links/